# Error handler for MBassador message/event bus

Tags: error-handling, mbassador

I'm using [MBassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador) 1.2.1 message/event bus. Works well. Except that I am getting this error message in my logs, repeated for each of my instantiated bus objects:

> WARN: No error handler configured to handle exceptions during publication.
>   Error handlers can be added to any instance of  AbstractPubSubSupport or via BusConfiguration. 
>   Falling back to console logger.

The [main project page](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador) shows this example line on a `BusConfiguration` object:

```
.addPublicationErrorHandler( new IPublicationErrorHandler{...} )
```

…yet neither my [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) nor I see any such method on the [`BusConfiguration`](http://bennidi.github.io/mbassador/net/engio/mbassy/bus/config/BusConfiguration.html) class.

How should I go about installing an error handler for Mbassador?

Answer (score 3):

Add it as another property when building the configuration bus:

```
    IBusConfiguration config = new BusConfiguration()
            .addFeature(Feature.SyncPubSub.Default())
            .addFeature(Feature.AsynchronousHandlerInvocation.Default())
            .addFeature(Feature.AsynchronousMessageDispatch.Default())
            .setProperty(Properties.Common.Id, "Command Channel Bus")
            .setProperty(Properties.Handler.PublicationError, new IPublicationErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleError(PublicationError error) {

                }
            });
```

I had the exact same issue as you and this solved my problem.